# All search indexes missing

Tags: solr, indexing, paas

Recently created a Sitecore PaaS instance associating with Solr IaaS, The Index Manager Console looks to be empty. What is wrong here !

[image]

Comment: If you open your `/showconfig.aspx` and search for the node `<indexes`, can you see any index on its children nodes?

Comment: Usually it happens in case having any SOLR connectivity issue. Could you check you connection strings and try access SOLR via browser. Make sure you use SSL protocol within SOLR. Then, if SOLR accessible, check the logging tab in SOLR. If there are any records in red, it can also be a reason of your issue.

Comment: yes, typical reason is that Sitecore cannot connect to solr or even could not connect when application was starting, if solr will start responding later Sitecore can still show empty list here (app pool restart is a solution on local environment)

Comment: Exact issue was SSL. I was able to connect via `http`, but `https` gave me a secure warning. The section (from file `solr.in.cmd` in my `(folder)\solr-7.2.1\bin`) didn't have the valid lines uncommented (with the correct values). (lines 102 - 111) enables SSL w/ correct cert from keystore

Answer (score 6):

In my case, I'm always doing this to fix that :

- Make sure your Sitecore configured properly for SOLR within
  \App_Config\Sitecore\ContentSearch
- Check your connectionstrings for SOLR is configured properly or not
- Access SOLR admin (with browser, make sure it's https) to check whether it's on or not
- If it's on, check again if your configured index matches with SOLR
  Core Admin
- If everything's ok, can try to recycle app pool for your site and
  wait a few minutes  Check again from the control panel

Make sure your SOLR Server turned on first before your Sitecore sites

Answer (score 1):

After spending essentially days trying to figure out why my Sitecore instance wasn't recognizing my Solr instance I updated my connection string to the following:

`<add name="solr.search" connectionString="http://solr:8983/solr" />`

Note the `solr:8983` in place of `localhost:8983`.
Be sure to test this address in your browser prior to using in your connection string file. The `https` vs `http` also matters so again be sure to test in your browser. Also, while debugging this I recommend you disable all of your custom index config files: You can do this by appending `.DISABLED` to the end of the file. If you have custom indexes they'd typically be located within:

- \App_Config\Include\zz.Foundation\Search
- \App_Config\Sitecore\ContentSearch

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had a proxy configured but not run.

I use Fiddler and it was configured but the Fiddler was not run.

**Before:**

```
<system.net>
    <defaultProxy useDefaultCredentials="true" enabled="true" xdt:Transform="Insert">
        <proxy usesystemdefault="false" proxyaddress="http://127.0.0.1:8888" bypassonlocal="false" autoDetect="false"/>
    </defaultProxy>
</system.net>
```

**After:**

```
<!--<system.net>
    <defaultProxy useDefaultCredentials="true" enabled="true" xdt:Transform="Insert">
        <proxy usesystemdefault="false" proxyaddress="http://127.0.0.1:8888" bypassonlocal="false" autoDetect="false"/>
    </defaultProxy>
</system.net>-->
```